# Rails aborted migrate command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dbmigrate

In trying to do the command **$rails db:migrate**, I receive the following error:

```
    $ rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
    rails aborted!
    StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
    Directly inheriting from ActiveRecord::Migration is not supported. Please specify the Rails release the migration was written for:
```

How do I specify the release the migration was written for? What file is this in? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails prevent from inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Migration` that's because migration API can change between different versions.

To solve it provide the version that you need for all your migration files:
`ActiveRecord::Migration[version_number]`

```rb
class MigrationClassName < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
end
```

Comment: Hi thank you for this! I didn't receive a notification to this question. As I've said, I'm very new to this... where exactly do I add this line? What file?

Comment: Add it to all files inside `db/migrate`. Just add the version at the end of every `ActiveRecord::Migration`. Also, what Rails version you use? what is the value of executing `ActiveRecord::Migration.current_version` in Rails console?

Comment: Thank you! That helped and executed the command successfully!

Comment: Also, I'm using `ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-linux]`